# Text in column not aligning to the start of the screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Search'),
            controller: city,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: citynamechanger,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  '$cityname',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80),
                ),
              ),
              FittedBox(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Temperature:$temp' + '\u2103',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Feels-like:$feelslike' + '\u2103',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Pressure:$pressure',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('get location'),
                      onPressed: geolocation,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I wanted to align all my weather properties (temp n all) to the left of the screen. I used crossAxis Alignment. start still it is not aligning it to the start of the screen[image: Like in this pic here]. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please Add into the first column 
 CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

Comment: It worked !  Thanks ! also, how do I center my raised button and ' London' then ?

Comment: use the Align widget

Comment: Simple center widget